# Unable to interpret program's output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  static int a=1;
  ++a;
  printf("%d",a);
  if(a<=3)
      main();
   printf("%d,a");   

}
```

I could not understand why the o/p is : 234444 . Can any one explain ?

**According to me , it should be 2344 as soon as a value reaches 4 , it should fail if condition and will not call main again.**

how could this happen ?

Comment: Calling main from within your program is undefined, and may break on some platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of three `main`s are:

```
main #1: 2         4
main #2:   3     4
main #3      4 4
```

BTW, `printf("%d,a");` should be `printf("%d",a)`;

To illustrate it, try

```
int depth = 0;

void main()
{
    ++depth;

    static int a = 1;
    ++a;
    printf("%d:%d ", depth, a);
    if (a <= 3)
        main();
    printf("%d:%d ", depth, a);

    --depth;
}
```

Output:

```
1:2 2:3 3:4 3:4 2:4 1:4
```

Comment: the first main#1 output is 2, but the reasoning is sound

Comment: how could 1 will be printed..can you please explain ?

Comment: @AlexD..nice explantion..Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
- main()
- ++a, now == 2
- print 2
  - main()
  - ++a, now == 3
  - print 3
    - main()
    - ++a, now == 4
    - don't call main
    - print 4
    - return
  - print 4
  - return
- print 4
- return
```

Comment: Fantastic..I believe this is what happening exactly..thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Each run of `main()` finishes by outputting the value of `a`, after its recursive call. The function will get run three times; the first run will output `2`, then recurse, then output `4`. In between, another invocation will output `3`, then recurse, then output `4`. In between, anther invocation will output `4`, then **not** recurse, then output `4`.

The only place I've seen such code is in totally artificial coding tests, where you're asked to determine the output of something absurd. Is that where this came from? **Don't waste your time with such things:** no one should ever be writing code like this, and being able to work out how it behaves is not a good indicator of programming ability.

Answer (score 0):

you declare a variable "a" as static, so when you enter the main(), the value is no longer initialized, and remained the same, otherwise you would get an infinite loop and stack overflow :)
here so interesting:

```
void main(int a)
{
    ++a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    if(a<=3)
        main(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);   
}
```